# How to use query_string with the filter in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, kibana

I have a simple query

```
GET data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "last_name": "test"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "henderson OR Boulder City OR Sloan",
                "fields": [
                  "city_*"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to change the `query_string` to a filter. I'm not sure how to convert

```
      {
          "bool": {
            "should": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "henderson OR Boulder City OR Sloan",
                "fields": [
                  "city_*"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

into something like

```
      "filter": {
        "query_string": {
              "query": "henderson OR Boulder City OR Sloan",
              "fields": [
                  "city_*"
              ]
          }
      }
```

and make sure it filters by all this cities `henderson OR Boulder City OR Sloan` and by all this fields `city_*.keyword`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
{
      "bool": {
        "should": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "henderson OR Boulder City OR Sloan",
            "fields": [
              "city_*"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

to

```
  {
      "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "henderson OR Boulder City OR Sloan",
            "fields": [
              "city_*"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Does this get your desired behavior? Using the same query under a filter should give you the same results as should, but the scoring will not be weighted by the query.

Edit - One more recommendation I would make is to adjust your query to this:

```
GET data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "last_name": "test"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "henderson OR Boulder City OR Sloan",
              "fields": [
                "city_*"
                ]
          }
        }
      ]        
    }
  }
}
```

Edit 2 - You may be able to move away from using query_string, does this give you any speed increase? (you could change should to the "shoulds" to be nested within a filter as well if you want them unscored)

```
GET data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "last_name": "test"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city_*": "henderson"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city_*": "Boulder City"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city_*": "Sloan"
          }
        }
      ]        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it does give me the same results..  my idea for using `filter` was to make the query a bit faster, but it seems it takes the same about of time

Comment: Filter and should, in the example you provided, will give you the same results (and I assume be approximately the same in expense). The only difference is that should will be scored and filter will not.

Comment: @Patrioticcow So that is a slightly different question than just updating the existing query to function as a filter, but there are a few approaches you could take. It may be best to swap out the query string operation entirely and search individual terms as an array.

Comment: I edited it one more possible approach you could take if you can get away from the query_string query. Let me know if this has a performance improvement for you if you're able to do so.

Comment: seems like `query_string` is a bit faster than breaking it down using `should`

Comment: Works like a charm.